# How do I run protractor from source code

Tags: protractor

I cloned the protractor code from github (https://github.com/angular/protractor)

Is there a way to run the code from the source code? The documentation is always mentions to install protractor with "npm install", but I want to run the latest code.

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install` in this context is meant to install the local dependencies for protractor.

You need to just run the `protractor` script in the bin folder.

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/protractor.git
cd protractor 
npm install

cd bin/
./protractor /path/to/e2e/e2e-conf.js
```